# Negative float values validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am  stuck with validation of  float value. I want to allow positive and negative
float values.
I tried  following  block on keypress  of input box

```
function allowFloatingNumberOnly(e, id){
    if ((e.which !=45  ) && (e.which !=46 || $(id).val().indexOf('.') != -1 ) && e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Where  `id`  is id of the input text. It fails with negative char. 
I am  able to  give  input  like  43--44,  -43-211.
I want to prevent user from entering  negative char in wrong  place.
Thanks

Comment: Why not just use `parseFloat()` and check the result for `NaN`?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - [because](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseFloat#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: @Amit thats `Number.parseFloat()`, not `parseFloat(value)`, which is universally supported. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - so silly of me :-) I wasn't certain, so I looked it up, and  didn't notice it's `Number`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Number()` function to check whether a number is a valid number:

```
function isValid(str) {
    return !isNaN(Number(str));
}
```

It sounds like you want to go beyond that and validate whether the next key will lead to an invalid number. That's more tricky, but here's one way to do it:

```js
$(function () {
    $('input.number').on('input', function () {
        var $el = $(this);
            val = $el.val(),
            oldValue = $el.data('oldValue');

        if (val !== '-' && 
            isNaN(Number(val)) && 
            val !== oldValue) {
            $el.val(oldValue);
        } else {
            $el.data('oldValue', val);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <input class="number" type="text" />
    <div>
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input class="number" type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
```